# Command-Prompt commands in Explorer Address Bar

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

Normally when I type **cmd** in explorer address bar (in any path), the black *Command-Prompt* windows opens in that address. Today I made a folder in my desktop with the name of "cmd"! and now when I type **cmd** in explorer address bar (in any path), the folder that I made on desktop opens. why?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is searching function of Windows, it will take the first matched item and execute it.

I try to make **cmd** folder in D:\ drive then I goto C:\ drive, type **cmd** on address bar, *Command-Prompt* windows is opened.

In another way, when I am at any path of D:\ drive then type **cmd** on address bar, **cmd** folder is opened instead of Command-Prompt windows.

Comment: try to make a **cmd** folder under another folder in D:\ drive and retry. that's weird. in both path of C:\ drive and D:\ drive CommandPrompt will open